# Spawn a background process and have a blocking wait on it to finish

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

My scenario is this: I need to run, in the background, a python script(process 2) from another python script(process 1). I want to then have a blocking wait on process 2 in script 1, as I would like to consume the files output by script 2. For example, consider this minimal example:

script 1

```py
import subprocess
import time

def get_pid_from_line(line):
    temp = [x for x in line.split() if len(x) != 0]
    return int(temp[1])

def blocking_wait(pid):
    while True:
        ps_output = subprocess.check_output("ps -ef | grep -E 'python.*<defunct>'", shell=True).decode("utf-8")
        ps_list = [line.strip() for line in ps_output.split("\n") if len(line.strip()) != 0]
        ps_list = [get_pid_from_line(line) for line in ps_list]
    
        if(pid in ps_list):
            break
        
        time.sleep(5)

p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "test2.py", "&"], shell=False)  # shell false required to get the correct pid, no longer can use string command :P
print(p.pid, type(p.pid))
# subprocess.call(f"wait {p.pid}", shell=True) # this again doesn't work
blocking_wait(p.pid)
print("world")
```

script 2

```py
import time
import sys

for i in range(10):
    print("hello")
    time.sleep(2)
```

This code works but the issue I am facing is that after script 2 is finished, process 2(with pid `p.pid` in script 1) becomes a zombie and thus I search for pid in the list of zombie python processes. Why should this happen? Also, the logic for searching if a pid is a zombie python process seems brittle. I tried using `wait pid` but the issue is that it is non-blocking and this would break my logic as the files would not have yet been created. In general, this solution works but is not elegant, is there a better way to do this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it fits to your application, but I usually use `events` from the multiprocessing-module.

The concept is a very simple signaling behavior as all threads/processes have access to this signal. In your case it would be like:

1. clear event in process 1 - `event.clear()`
2. Start process 2
3. wait for event in process 1 - `event.wait()`
4. set event in process 2 when finished - `event.set()`

As soon as `event.set()` is called, all processes/threads that are waiting on this event are resuming their work immediately.